# How to reduce the gap between HTML5 video tag

Tags: css, html5-video

How to reduce the gap between two video tag, I have tried with margin and padding its not worked any help are appreciated

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Ng6XU/1/)

**My HTML**

```
<div class="videoTest">
    <video controls="controls"></video>
    <video controls="controls"></video>
    <video controls="controls"></video>
    <video controls="controls"></video>
</div>
```

**My CSS**

```
.videoTest > video{
    border:1px solid red;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;    
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the link which gives various method to solve this issue, may be helpful to some one [Reference : http://css-tricks.com](http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/)

Published April 21, 2012 by Chris Coyier

Here's the deal: a series of inline-block elements formatted like you normally format HTML will have spaces in between them.

In other words:

```
<nav>
  <a href="#">One</a>
  <a href="#">Two</a>
  <a href="#">Three</a>
</nav>

nav a {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px;
  background: red;
}
```

Will result in:

Often highly undesirable (check the link for the output)

We often want the elements to butt up against each other. In the case of navigation, that means it avoids the awkward little unclickable gaps.

This isn't a "bug" (I don't think). It's just the way setting elements on a line works. You want spaces between words that you type to be spaces right? The spaces between these blocks are just like spaces between words. That's not to say the spec couldn't be updated to say that spaces between inline-block elements should be nothing, but I'm fairly certain that is a huge can of worms that is unlikely to ever happen.

Here's some ways to fight the gap and get inline-block elements sitting directly next to each other.
Remove the spaces

The reason you get the spaces is because, well, you have spaces between the elements (a line break and a few tabs counts as a space, just to be clear). Minimized HTML will solve this problem, or one of these tricks:

```
<ul>
  <li>
   one</li><li>
   two</li><li>
   three</li>
</ul>
```

or

```
<ul>
  <li>one</li
  ><li>two</li
  ><li>three</li>
</ul>
```

or with comments...

```
<ul>
  <li>one</li><!--
  --><li>two</li><!--
  --><li>three</li>
</ul>
```

They're all pretty funky, but it does the trick.
Negative margin

You can scoot the elements back into place with negative 4px of margin (may need to be adjusted based on font size of parent). Apparently this is problematic in older IE (6 & 7), but if you don't care about those browsers at least you can keep the code formatting clean.

```
nav a {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: -4px;
}
```

Skip the closing tag

HTML5 doesn't care anyway. Although you gotta admit, it feels weird.

```
<ul>
  <li>one
  <li>two
  <li>three
</ul>
```

Set the font size to zero

A space that has zero font-size is... zero width.

```
nav {
  font-size: 0;
}
nav a {
  font-size: 16px;
}
```

Matt Stow reports that the font-size: 0; technique has some problems on Android. Quote: "Pre-Jellybean does not remove the space at all, and Jellybean has a bug whereby the last element randomly has a tiny bit of space." See research.
Also note, if you're sizing fonts in ems, this zero font size thing can be an issue, since ems cascade the children would also have zero font size. Rems would be of help here, otherwise any other non-cascading font-size to bump it back up.
Another weirdness! Doug Stewart showed me that if you use @font-face with this technique, the fonts will lose anti-aliasing in Safari 5.0.x. (test case) (screenshot).
Just float them instead

Maybe they don't need to be inline-block at all, maybe they can just be floated one way or another. That allows you to set their width and height and padding and stuff. You just can't center them like you can by text-align: center; the parent of inline-block elements. Well... you kinda can but it's weird.
Just use flexbox instead

If the browser support is acceptable to you and what you need out of inline-block is centering, you could use flexbox. They aren't exactly interchangeable layout models or anything, but you might get what you need out of it.

Answer (score 13):

The `<video>` element is an inline element by default. That's why there are gaps between them representing the whitespaces and/or line-breaks in your markup.

```
.videoTest > video {
    display: inline-block;
    border:1px solid red;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;    
}

.videoTest {
    font-size: 0;
}
```

By using `font-size: 0`, the line-breaks and whitespaces are being kind of ignored and you get rid of the gaps. Their size is set to 0.

[**Updated Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ng6XU/9/)

This is a common workaround when working with `inline-blocks` and is in some situations superior to `floats` when it comes to centering for example.

Comment: its working but float:left also need to get the element side by side too, and only the float:left also working +1 for your ans

Comment: I updated my answer, you only need to add `font-size: 0` to get rid of the gaps

Comment: Your effort is good, I feel this is not a good solution because if we want to add the text in that div it will not be displayed, is there any issue in using the float property?

Comment: There is problem with adding text. If there is a paragraph inside the `.videoTest` you can simply add `p { font-size: 12px }`. Floats need to be cleared if you need to use your parent containers height. There are some difficulties centering multiple elements in the same row if floated or breaking rows for elements with different heights. http://robertnyman.com/2010/02/24/css-display-inline-block-why-it-rocks-and-why-it-sucks/ Article on `inline-blocks`

Answer (score 3):

try this

http://jsfiddle.net/Ng6XU/5/

```
.videoTest > video{
    border:1px solid red;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0; 
    float:left;
}
```

Comment: minus margin is not a good practice is it? even though it has the space between height [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Ng6XU/4/)

Comment: I wouldn't advice using `floats` or negative `margins` as long as there are more simple solutions like changing the `display` property.

Comment: @KilianStinson but if we used the only `display:block` we cant get the element next to each like `inline` that time we want to use the float is it?

Comment: Ups, my fault. Due to my low resolutions the elements we're all in a new row.

Comment: @KilianStinson [see this](http://jsfiddle.net/Ng6XU/1/embedded/result/) hope you will see the floated element

Answer (score 3):

TRY THIS CSS :

```
.videoTest > video{
    border:1px solid red;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;    
    float:left;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since the video tag defaults as an inline-block element, simply make the video tag a block element in CSS.  Bob's your uncle.

```
video {display: block;}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would say that in my case setting this css helped:

> height:auto;

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was using 640x480 for the video size. I changed it to 640x360 and that removed the white space above the video.